# How to enable dependency profiling graphs | Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, dependency, command, profiler, graph

According to [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html) article we can enable dependency profiling graph but did not find any command for the same.

As Mentioned on the page - To enable dependency graphs, use the **"variable option"**. See attached screenshot.

[image]

What is the meaning of "**variable option**" here?

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck on this question?

Answer (score 0):

i succeeded to view dependency graph by adding following line to app/code/etc/env.php:

```
'MAGE_PROFILER' => 2,
```